# Publishing metadata (.xml) for every single row in table on GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, metadata, csw

**How do I publish metadata in xml format for every single row in a table via Geoserver?**

In details, **I know i can use GeoNetwork or OpenGeo Suite(Boundless) for publish metadatas** but I am very curious about publishing the metadatas using just Geoserver. If I want to publish metadata files for single layers, **I add a metadata links in description of layer in Geoserver.
[Metadata Import in GeoServer for layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX45f.png) but it doesn't work for every single rows in table.**

**Note 1:** I have already installed CSW plug-in for GeoServer.

**Note 2:** I cant find any examples metadatas which published in GeoServer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, without code changes there is no way to publish metadata on a per record basis, only on a layer basis